# skmaps in mobile is slow

Tags: openstreetmap, skmaps

We use the skmaps's(Skobbler) SDK in android and IOS,
Our function is to show one pin in skmaps, the other settings is default.
We can show the map on both android and IOS, 
but the loading time is too long, it takes about 5~15 seconds.

I've been trying different Wifi network and different device(iphone 6s plus and HTC M9), but it's still slow.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Perhaps this question is better suited to http://forum.skobbler.com/forum.php or emailing info@skobbler.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SDK doesn’t seem to be slow at rendering. 
So check the downloading process for the requested vector tiles.
How to improve it:

- reduce the requested area - increase the zoom level so that as soon as some vector data becomes available something will get rendered (i.e. set the zoom level to 18 or 17)
- reduce the size of the requested vector tiles - switch to using LightMaps (initMapSettings.setMapDetailLevel(SKMapsInitSetti ngs.SK_MAP_DETAIL_LIGHT) - the light maps contain fewer elements and thus are smaller and will be rendered faster
- don't use pannable maps but use static maps when displaying the location of a certain POI - for this exact use case, showing a mini map associated with a POI most products use a static map (fixed png/jpg) as it renders instantly. This is especially relevant in scenarios when the POIs are in different parts of the world